# How to filter arrays depending on the values of arrays inside the array?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Why doesn't this test pass?

```
it('lodash_test', function() {
    var arr = [{a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}, {a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}, {a: "x", b: [{x: "33", y: "2"}]}]
    var result = _.filter(arr, function(obj) {
        obj.b.forEach(function(item_b) {
            if(item_b.x=="1") {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    expect(result).to.be.eql([{a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}, {a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `forEach`'s return value is completely ignored, and your `_.filter` predicate function never returns anything.

You probably wanted to use `some`:

```
it('lodash_test', function() {
    var arr = [{a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}, {a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}, {a: "x", b: [{x: "33", y: "2"}]}]
    var result = _.filter(arr, function(obj) {
        return obj.b.some(function(item_b) {
    //  ^^^^^^^      ^^^^
            if(item_b.x=="1") {
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
    expect(result).to.be.eql([{a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}, {a: "x", b: [{x: "1", y: "2"}]}]);
});
```

`Array#some` calls the predicate for each entry in the array, stopping the first time the predicate returns a truthy value; its return value is `true` if the predicate ever returned a truthy value, or `false` if not.

So the `return` I've underscored in the above is the return from the `_.filter` predicate; your original `return true` is the return from `some` (formerly `forEach`).

Comment: You're a genius :) Thank you! By the way, do you think that it is a performant way to do the job? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: @scaryguy: I think for a small data set, it doesn't matter. It's simple and gets the job done. Worry about performance if and when performance is an issue. :-) Having said that, based on the structure of the data, I'm not immediately seeing how you could do it other than what you're doing; you have to loop through the inner arrays to know if they have `x == "1"`. The JavaScript engine's going to optimize those predicate calls (and even if it didn't, [they don't cost anything worth worrying about](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)).

Comment: I'm going to use this for an ad server. Instead of doing the same thing in MongoDB, I'm fetching a base number of records and I'm iterating over them to filter odd ones. Maybe it's a very broad question for a "comment" but do you think so this should be more performant than a "db query"? If you'd like to answer, I can add another question for this :)